# WP - Attribute and filter Region Sizing (EU, UK, US..)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, attributes, custom-wordpress-pages

[Here](http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/26308/nike-air-zoom-talaria-mid-fk-premium) is what I’m trying to achieve:

As you can see here, you can choose shoe size based on the region (EU, UK, US).

After lot of research, I found the solution from *@Hambos22* [there](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shoes-region-sizing/#post-8619935) to be exactly the one I am trying to do. But impossible to put in place neither *@Hambos22* or *@mikejolley* solution.
I think that I am missing some knowledge where to put these parts of code as I am trying to put everything inside *'function.php'* but it's only displaying me 
the switcher.

I’ve added 2 more custom fields in the Attribute *size* (UK, US).

[My website link](https://eshoes.com.au/product/martini-osvaldo-728-suede-blue/)

My attribute slug: **size**

Variables added with ACF: **uk-size**, **us-size**

My attribute default value: *EU*

### *Code I would like to put in place (but don't know the location):*

**Here is a php snippet**

```
$us_size = get_field('us_size', $term);
    $uk_size = get_field('uk_size', $term);
    $cm_size = get_field('cm_size', $term);
    printf( '<div class="sizeRadio">
        <input type="radio" name="%1$s" value="%2$s" id="%3$s" %4$s>
        <label for="%3$s">
        <span class="label_show" data-region="eu">%5$s</span>
        <span data-region="us">%6$s</span>
        <span data-region="uk">%7$s</span>
        <span data-region="cm">%8$s</span>
        </label>
        </div>', $input_name, $esc_value, $id, $checked, $filtered_label, $us_size, $uk_size, $cm_size );
}
```

**Here is a JS snippet**

```
$('[data-chooseregion]').on('click', function(e) {
                        $(this).addClass('active--sizeSelect').siblings().removeClass('active--sizeSelect');

                        var $active = $('[data-region=' + $(this).data('chooseregion') + ']').addClass('label_show');

                        $('[data-region]').not($active).removeClass('label_show');
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

**Here is the markup for the switcher**

```
<?php
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect active--sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="eu" href="#">EU</a>';
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="us" href="#" >US</a>';
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="uk" href="#" >UK</a>';
    echo '<a class="sizeSelect" data-chooseregion="cm" href="#" >CM</a>';
?>
```

Anyone could help me to sort it out?

By the way I would also love to apply that to [my shop page](https://eshoes.com.au/shop/) as a filter in the left panel!

If any more information needed don't hesitate I would reply in less than 12 hours.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the single product page:**

I finally sort it out and instead of creating a "dynamic" data's change, I chose to create a table from the 2 fields under my pa_size as follow:

```
if(!empty($terms)){
    echo '<button class="accordion">Size Chart <i class="fa-sitemap"></i></button>
        <div class="panel">
            <table class="sf-table standard_bordered"><tbody><tr><td><strong>EU</strong></td>';
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $eu_s = get_field('eu-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                    echo '<td>'. $eu_s .'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr><tr><td><strong>UK</strong></td>';
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $uk_s = get_field('uk-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                    echo '<td>'. $uk_s .'</td>';
                }
            echo '</tr><tr><td><strong>US</strong></td>';   
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $us_s = get_field('us-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                    echo '<td>'. $us_s .'</td>';
                }   
            echo '</tr></tbody></table></div>';
}
```

**For the Filter on WC Shop page:**

I've created a new "widget" going to my filter panel and also installed the handy plugin **PHP Text Widget** which Extends the default WordPress text widget making it able to execute PHP code.

Then put the following code in it:

```
<div class="filter-size">
<input type="button" name="filterEU" value="EU" onclick="sizesEU()" />
<input type="button" name="filterUK" value="UK" onclick="sizesUK()" />
<input type="button" name="filterUS" value="US" onclick="sizesUS()" />
</div>

    <?php
        global $product;
        $terms = get_terms( 'pa_size', $args );
        $page_url = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );?>

    <div id="filterEU"> 
        <ul class="jcaa_attr_select jcaa_attr_variable_select  jcaa_size_medium">
            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ):
            $slug = $term->slug;
            $num = (float)$slug;
            if ($num > 20){
                $eu_s = get_field('eu-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $uk_s = get_field('uk-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $us_s = get_field('us-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $term_link = $page_url . 'product-tag/cf-size-eu-' . $eu_s . '-uk-' . $uk_s . '-us-' . $us_s; ?>
                <li><a class="jcaa_attr_option jcaa_obj_text" href="<?php echo esc_url($term_link ); ?>"><?php echo $eu_s ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="filterUK" style="display:none">
        <ul class="jcaa_attr_select jcaa_attr_variable_select  jcaa_size_medium">
            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ):
            $slug = $term->slug;
            $num = (float)$slug;
            if ($num > 20){
                $eu_s = get_field('eu-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $uk_s = get_field('uk-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $us_s = get_field('us-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $term_link = $page_url . 'product-tag/cf-size-eu-' . $eu_s . '-uk-' . $uk_s . '-us-' . $us_s; ?>
                <li><a class="jcaa_attr_option jcaa_obj_text" href="<?php echo esc_url($term_link ); ?>"><?php echo $uk_s ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>          
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="filterUS" style="display:none">
        <ul class="jcaa_attr_select jcaa_attr_variable_select  jcaa_size_medium">
            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ):
            $slug = $term->slug;
            $num = (float)$slug;
            if ($num > 20){
                $eu_s = get_field('eu-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $uk_s = get_field('uk-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $us_s = get_field('us-size', 'pa_size_' . $term->term_id);
                $term_link = $page_url . 'product-tag/cf-size-eu-' . $eu_s . '-uk-' . $uk_s . '-us-' . $us_s; ?>
                <li><a class="jcaa_attr_option jcaa_obj_text" href="<?php echo esc_url($term_link ); ?>"><?php echo $us_s ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>  
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
    function sizesEU() {
       document.getElementById('filterEU').style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById('filterUK').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('filterUS').style.display = "none";
    }
    function sizesUK() {
       document.getElementById('filterEU').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('filterUK').style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById('filterUS').style.display = "none";
    }
    function sizesUS() {
       document.getElementById('filterEU').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('filterUK').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('filterUS').style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
```

Don't hesitate if any question about it.

Cheers